# def __unicode__ returns a non foriegn key element of another table

Tags: django

models.py

```
class userdetails(models.Model):
    userid=models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    emailid=models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.firstname


class studdetails(models.Model):
    total=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    fkid=models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.userdetails.firstname
```

I tried to get the first name field of the userdetails table where studdetails.fkid=userdetails.userid. Any one can help? please!

Comment: How are userdetails, and studdetails related ?

Comment: Errrr… are you handling foreign keys manually?

Comment: yes, i'm storing the same unique value to these 2 fields

Comment: I still don't see how `self` have a `userdetails`: `return self.userdetails.firstname`

Comment: i know the last line is wrong, i dont know how to return the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, I got result, by using the following code.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    try:
        ud = User.objects.get(userid=self.fkid)
        return u'%s - %s -%s' %(ud.first_name , ud.last_name ,ud.email_address)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try not to handle the Foreign keys and the ids manually

Use [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) column type for your models to relate to the foreign table/model

Try this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.firstname

class Student(models.Model):
    total = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.firstname
```

Comment: is there any other way to get my expected result, without using foreign key?

Comment: because userid field is a random number that i generated in my code and then i stored in userdetails table.

Comment: auto generation field should be the unique field for userdetails table and studdetails table have some other auto generation field as unique, and userid=kfid. this is the requirement

Comment: requirement from who @ijarlax ? I am still confused as to why you can't use the django ForeignKeys

Comment: this is related to my project. k neal is there any way to do this?

Comment: requirement of my project. Want auto generation field as pk, and this random number generation field to act as foreign key as manually

Comment: arrrg I am sure you can set the fk to your autogen value.. django is very expandable like that.